# Select a column that potentially doesn't exist in Oracle dictionary views

Tags: sql, oracle, compatibility, information-schema

I want to create a backwards compatible query on `SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS`. In Oracle 11g, the useful `ALL_ARGUMENTS.DEFAULTED` column was added. Now if I run this query against Oracle 10g:

```
SELECT defaulted FROM all_arguments
```

I get an error, of course.

> ORA-00904: "SYS"."ALL_ARGUMENTS"."DEFAULTED": invalid identifier

What I'd like to do is this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column_exists("defaulted") 
            THEN defaulted 
            ELSE 'N'
       END
FROM all_arguments
```

Or even better

```
SELECT evaluate_column_on_current_row(column_name           => "defaulted", 
                                      default_if_not_exists => 'N')
FROM all_arguments
```

Is there some way to do that in a single SQL query, without resorting to PL/SQL? Or should I check the Oracle version first like this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM all_tab_cols
WHERE owner = 'SYS'
AND table_name = 'ALL_ARGUMENTS'
AND column_name = 'DEFAULTED'
```

Comment: @Arion: ORA-00904... See the updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query that references a column that doesn't exist can't generate a valid plan.

You need to choose an approach where the queries submitted are always valid.  Be that dynamically generating/executing them, or some other approach.

But if you submit a query to be parsed, and it contains a non existant field on an existant table, the parser will throw it back at you.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that maybe there is some system function to evaluate an expression given the current row in the projection.

Obviously, this is not optimal for execution plan generation, but I don't see why this shouldn't be possible in principle... I've added a better example to the question, with fully dynamic column name evaluation

Comment: @LukasEder - Simplistically, because SQL is compiled.  If you want a level of indirection, where-by the field names are lookuped up at run-time, the solution *is* dynamic SQL.  There are many reasons for this; the simplest one is that, when a query is submitted to be parsed and compiled, various stats and other details are checked (indexes, constraints, selectivity, etc) to form a plan.  That plan is then fixed for *that* query.  If you submit an even slightly different query, you get a new plan.  It's just the way SQL works.  For your initial example, dynamic SQL seems perfectly suited to me.